# Why is my .config always being assigned to the bottom right button?

Tags: python, lambda

When'People .config' runs it only changes the bottom right button, is there any way to change it so that whichever button in my grid is clicked changes colour.

```
def click(row, col):

    label.configure(text="you booked row %s column %s" % (row, col), bg='black', fg='yellow', font='Times 
    22')
    print("you booked row %s column %s" % (row, col))
    People.config(bg='red')






root.configure(bg="black")
Seats = Frame(root, height=100, width =200, bg = 'black')
Seats.grid(row=0, column = 1)

for row in range(10):

    for col in range(20):
        People = Button(Seats, bg='Orange',text="%s,%s" % (row, col),
                       command=lambda row=row, col=col: click(row, col))


        People.grid(row=row, column=col+1, pady=1,padx=1)
```

Comment: ***it only changes the bottom right button***: You use `People` which refers to the last `Button` from the `for ...` loop. Follow this approach [Using a event callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60197776/7414759)